# Using an ES module in TailwindCSS config (Using React and Craco)

Tags: javascript, create-react-app, tailwind-css, es6-modules, craco

I've been trying for hours to import the package `d3-colors` into my `tailwind.config.js`. No solutions I have found on the internet have worked so far.

I have tried:

- Converting it to `tailwind.config.mjs`, but then it doesn't get loaded. The configuration does not work.
- Using the `await import('colors-d3')` but that doesn't work either because then I have to await the function that gets it, and that's not allowed either:

```
module.exports = await config();
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
```

- I've tried changing the package to `type='module'`, but then I have all sorts of issues with Craco not being able to load it's config once I convert it to an ESM module because craco itself is commonjs.
- I have tried modifying Craco's config...
- I've tried using a postcss config file to pass the `tailwind.config.mjs` as the config file parameter, doesn't work either.

etc etc

I can't get it to work. How can I just import this module into my tailwind config?

Comment: Have you done `require('d3-colors')`?

Answer (score 1):

According to the team, they won't be supporting ESM anytime soon.

https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/8029#issuecomment-1086875656